# Installshield error 1001 without installshield installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installshield-le

I have an application with an installshield installer. I install a service and a windows form.

Whenever I install the application on computers where I have installshield it installs, but when I try to install it on other machines it gives me Error 1001.

I am using Installshield LE, Visual Studio 2010. I am using the same OS on the development machines and on the machines where I would like to install, Windows 7.

Anyone has any idea how could that problem sorted? I tried to add all of the installshiled references what I could, but it did not change anything.

Regards
Daniel

Comment: I was having this problem also and I actually found the exact setting you have to change in InstallShield LE. I wrote it up how to fix it at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949860/error-1001-when-installing-custom-windows-service/38269757#38269757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`This installation error can occur because the incorrect version of InstallUtilLib.dll has been streamed into the MSI package for the .NET Installer Class custom actions.`

[Q112469: INFO: Error 1001 Occurs During Installation](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/INFO/Error-1001-Occurs-During-Installation)

Are you using both VS10 and VS12 ?

Have you activated the InstallShield ?

Comment: I am just using VS10, yes it is activated. If the .dll wrong then why it is working when I install installshield on the other computers?
The path for the installUtilLib is that: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
Is that right or should I be more specific?

Comment: OK I think it is sorted. My problem was that I used a the 32bit InstallUtilLib.dll instead of the 64bit.... Thank you

Comment: @Daniel, how do you specify the version?

Comment: @zaitsman Version of what? Visual studio or the installshield?

Comment: it doesn't look like there is anything relevant on that external link any more. It looks like some sort of menu page

Comment: Your link is old ... please use https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/INFO/Error-1001-Occurs-During-Installation

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact scenario and error, installing a service and one winform. It turns out I was getting the 1001 error (apparently) because my service was already running on that machine. (Which is why i suspect you were only getting the error on your development machine?) When I uninstalled the service through add/remove programs, the installation went as planned.

Comment: You are right, that can be a problem as well. Error 1001 can be many different thing. I had that issue before when one of the services had a second temporary service to help in installation which should be removed when installation finished, unfortunately it was not always removed. If it was not, then the main service could not get installed again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Mine was being caused by a similar service that was already installed. Uninstalling the already installed service worked for me.

Comment: You are right it could cause the same error to appear, if you have a service with the same name already installed.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have a referenced Framework that you have not installed in the server where you are trying to install your app, select installshield le in menu bar, select options and then .NET, finally select the framework's folder in my case was v2.0 because that's the framework i have installed in the server,

hope can help

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help some of you encountering the Error 1001 when trying to install a .NET Windows Service using InstallShield 2015 LE installer project with the Primary Output set as an Installer.

It's a known InstallShield bug when .NET 4.6 is installed on Windows 10.

https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/ISSUE/HOTFIX-Install-Fails-With-Error-1001-When-a-NET-Installer-Class-Component-is-Present-in-InstallShield-2015-SP1

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score -2):

Verify that you have the correct version of the .NET framework installed on the machine that you are installing the software to.   The version is shown in the project properties.